# Can one use the Laurent series to find the derivatives at the center of the annulus of convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, derivatives, laurent-series

I was asked to find the Laurent Series of $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z+1}-\frac{1}{z+4}$$ which I found to be, $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{z^n}{4^{n+1}}$$  Now how do I find $f^{17}(0)?$

The series above is  for $1<|z|<4$.

Comment: Laurent series in which annulus?

Comment: Sorry, I just added that. $1<|z|<4$

Comment: Okay. That Laurent series doesn't help you finding $f^{(17)}(0)$. For that, either use the Taylor series in $\mathbb{D}$, or compute the derivatives of the two summands directly.

Comment: Would this be the Taylor Series? $f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n z^n- \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{z^n}{4^{n+1}}$ for |z|<1.

Comment: Yes, that is it. Well, if you combine the two series, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(1-\frac{1}{4^{n+1}}\right)z^n$. Then you presumably know that the coefficient of $z^n$ is $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$.

Comment: I'm sorry. This is my last question. This $(-1)^n(1-\frac{1}{4^{n+1}})$ stuff, are these coefficients. I just need to make sure I understand this.

Comment: Yes, that's the coefficient. So take $n = 17$, evaluate, and multiply with $17!$.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Based on the comments by Daniel Fischer</sup>

---

No, the coefficients of Laurent series with the region of convergence $r<|z|<R$ with $r>0$ are not directly related to the derivatives of $f$ at $0$.

To find $f^{(17)}(0)$, either use the Taylor series in $\mathbb{D}$, or compute the derivatives of the two summands directly.

The Taylor series,  if you combine the two parts, is $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(1-\frac{1}{4^{n+1}}\right)z^n$$ Then use the fact that the coefficient of $z^n$ is $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$.